# Placer Holder in C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows

How to use place holder as string concatenation in C# windows form application...

I have tried console application it is working fine, but on windows form application it is not working

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Hello {0}", textBox1.Text);
}
```

The output should be like "Hello + TextBox.Text" but it gives "Hello {0}"

Comment: You're looking for `string.Format`

Answer (score 4):

Use `String.Format()`

```
MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Hello {0}", textBox1.Text));
```

Answer (score 4):

C# 6.0 supports string interpolation

```
MessageBox.Show($"Hello {textbox1.Text}")
```

Or you can use string.Format like others are saying.

Answer (score 2):

do a

```
string.Format("Hello {0}", textBox1.Text);
```

there is a difference in how things are done between dot net core and older frameworks.

Comment: This has nothing to do with .Net Core.

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter of [`MessageBox`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20stz12s(v=vs.110).aspx) is hold for caption of the `MessageBox`. So this code `MessageBox.Show("Hello {0}", textBox1.Text);` displays a `MessageBox` with `Hello {0}` as it's text  and the `textBox1.Text` as the caption of your `MessageBox`. You could use `String.Format` like this:

```
string result = string.Format("Hello {0}", textBox1.Text);
MessageBox.Show(result);
```